# Screen Painter shows wrong field names when adding fields from table KNA1

Tags: abap, dynpro

In the Screen Painter, I'm trying to add fields from table KNA1 declared globally in my program:

```
TABLES: VBAK, VBAP, KNA1.
```

What shows up in the program fields list are the fields from table VBAP assigned to table KNA1 The fields specific to KNA1 are not in the list.

In real life, there is no `VBELN` field in table `KNA1`, however there should be a `KUNNR` field.

How to fix this bug ?

[image]

Comment: As you can see, the scrollbar shows that the list is positioned at the middle of all fields. Just scroll up a little bit...

Comment: I know, I positioned it this way to show the attributes  available for KNA1. As you can see these aren't attributes of the real table KNA1 (for example there is no VBELN field in KNA1, however there should be a KUNNR field).

Comment: It may be a bug, what SAPGUI/Netweaver version do you use?

Comment: Check SAP notes or install latest SAP patches and latest SAP GUI. Or contact SAP support.